# android kotlin what is the current way of make sure viewPager2 pageItem resume is fired only when onscreen?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-viewpager2

I want init tasks (starting a countDownTimer) only when the viewPager2 pages become visible.
and stop timer when they get off-screen.
however, I got stuck on the fact that resume() is fired when off-screen for pageItem.

setUserVisibleHint seems deprecated, it seems sexMaxLifeCycle is current way, however, I am not sure how this can be called,
not sure whether call it within... and onHiddenChanged() does not work either.

```
class ToneFragmentStateAdapter(activity:FragmentActivity):FragmentStateAdapter(activity){

fun setItems(newItems: List<Tone4>) {
    _items = newItems
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

private var _items = listOf<Tone4>()

override fun getItemCount(): Int = _items.size

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment
= TonePageFragment.newInstance(position, _items[position])}
```

Comment: Code seems incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

`ViePager2` creates and attaches fragments off-screen for performance reasons. What you could do is implement a `ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback` and then have a method on your fragment that tells it is the currently active fragment.

For example

```kotlin
fun onPageSelected(position int) {
   adapter.items.forEachIndexed( index, fragment -> {
       fragment.setActive(position == index)
   }
}
```

Comment: onChangeCallBack is triggered when User slide from A to B (if success), B could be A-1 or A+1. for my requirement, I will need to figure out whether the user switch to A-1 or A+1 or even A(failure) to reactivate my timer on the new active page. in short this does not help much unless I missed something